# What is a Null Pointer Exception in webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

`null pointer exception` implementing selenium web driver concept. Let us take it is shopping site  when I am trying to write each class for each page  and each class has got some classes for their web elements in another class and when trying to call these class methods in one single test case for all pages it is returning `null pointer exception`.

Comment: Is it page object model you are using to create test cases? If yes then you need to provide an object of webdriver to your webelement class. Will be helpful if you can explain a bit more.

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can see what is giving you the NPE.

Comment: Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

Calling the instance method of a null object.
Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object.

Null pointer is the concept of Java... its not specific to WebDriver.. if you are facing any issues with your code.. please provide it.